# Remove common strings in multiple files and copy them

Tags: linux, bash

I would like to copy and rename all files in a folder that are matching this pattern:

- test.mp4.small.mp4
- test2.mp4.small.mp4
- test3.mp4.small.mp4

All files have in common that they end with `.mp4.small.mp4`.

I would like to copy them to a new folder and rename them - the result should be:

- test.mp4
- test2.mp4
- test3.mp4

Attempt:

```
find . -name '*.mp4.small.mp4' -exec bash -c 'echo cp $0 ${0/PATH/}' {} \;
```

But this does not rename it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the parameter expansion syntax for removing the shortest string from the beginning upto delimiter `.` of syntax `${word%string}` as

```
find . -name '*.mp4.small.mp4' -exec bash -c 'echo cp $0 ${0%.mp4.small.mp4}.mp4' {} \;
```

Also I assume, you *knowingly* have added the `echo` to just troubleshoot how the renamed string looks like. To actually copy the files, drop it in the final command.

Answer (score 0):

```
rename 's/.mp4.small//' *mp4.small.mp4
```

will not overwrite by default.

to test just to make sure:

```
ls *mp4.small.mp4 | sed 's/.mp4.small//' #list resulting file names
```